# Difference between concat and push?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, push

Why does a return of the `push` method cause

> Uncaught TypeError: acc.push is not a function

But a return `concat` results in the correct solution?

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function name(acc, curr) {
  if (even(curr)) {
    return acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


function even(number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function name(acc, curr) {
  if (even(curr)) {
    return acc.concat(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


function even(number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Because `push` returns a number while `concat` returns an array.

Comment: push pushes arrays as one item, concat concats arrays, or an array with an item, beside the different return types.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `push()` adds elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.  Thus your return here is invalid.

The `concat()` method is used to merge arrays. Concat does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Better to filter, if you want a NEW array like so:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  return (index % 2 === 0);
});
```

Note that assumes the array arr is complete with no gaps - all even indexed values.  If you need each individual, use the `element` instead of `index`

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  return (element% 2 === 0);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

According to the MDN document say that:

- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method: *adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array***.

```
const count = ['pigs', 'goats'].push('cows');
console.log(count); // expected output: 3
```

- [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method *is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays but instead **returns a new arra**y*

```
console.log(['a'].concat(['b']));// expected output: Array ["a", "b"]
```

And combined with the final [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#syntax)'s parameter is the array initialize `[])`, which means that *you want to return an array result*.

*==>* So that's the reason why in case that you use `concat` working well.

---

### Refactor code

1. If you still want to use `Array#reduce` and `Array#push`

```js
const even = (number) => number%2 === 0;
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function name(acc, curr) {
  if(even(curr)) acc.push(curr); // Just add one more item instead of return
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

2. The simpler way is to use `Array#filter`

```js
const even = (number) => number%2 === 0;
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(even));
```

Answer (score 7):

`acc` should not be an array. Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example#Parameters). It *can* be one, but..

It makes no sense at all to `reduce` an array to an array. What you want is `filter`. I mean, `reduce` using an array as the accumulator and `concat`ing each element to it technically does work, but it is just not the right approach.

```js
var res = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(even);
console.log(res);


function even(number) {
  return (number % 2 === 0);
}
```

Comment: I agree. It was an exam question, I was asked to reimplement filter by using  reduce. I had been a little fuzzy on the specs and was only looking for clarification.

Comment: Say you had an array of numbers that you want to transform to an an array of the running sum of those numbers eg. [1,2,7,4] -> [1,3,10,14]. In this case would reduce with acc being an array be appropriate?

Comment: Its a fine approach actually especially if you chain together operations to avoid running multiple loops, look up "transducers and loop fusion"

Comment: If you are transforming an array to another array with different values that is shorter (or longer) than the original, then reduce() is perfect.

Comment: I think that arr.filter is a better approach in this case. Although according to documentation you can use arr.reduce this wayI think that it is commonly accepted that .reduce is used to create one variable from all values in an array.

Answer (score 6):

https://dev.to/uilicious/javascript-array-push-is-945x-faster-than-array-concat-1oki
Concat is 945x slower than push only because it has to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

`concat()` creates a new array by merging the array the method is called on with all arguments flattened (1 level deep) into an array.

`push()` just adds elements to an existing array.

Since `concat()` creates a new array avoid it if you use a repetitive task like filling an array with values from another array, it's extremely slow:

```
` Chrome/117
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
create new array by push       1.0x  |  x10000  510  518  525  541  546
create new array by concat   109.8x  |    x100  560  565  572  582  590
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let people = [
  { name: "John", age: [30, 40], city: "New York" },
  { name: "Alice", age: [30, 40], city: "Los Angeles" },
  { name: "Bob", age: [30, 40], city: "Chicago" },
  { name: "Eva", age: [30, 60], city: "San Francisco" },
  { name: "David", age: [30, 50], city: "Miami" }
];

const COUNT = 3000;

// @benchmark create new array by push
{
let count = COUNT, result = [];
while(count--) result.push(...people);
result;
}

// @benchmark create new array by concat
{
let count = COUNT, result = [];
while(count--) result = result.concat(people);
}

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```